# Drupal page.tpl.php does not change

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I have tried it with many themes on Drupal but none works. I've tried to change different template files across different themes.
I've reenabled them, cleared caches but no changes showed up. It is as if the template is literally stored somewhere and kept intact.

When I rename the page.tpl.php file completely, drupal loads instead the template from module/system. So, I know that it reads the directory, I am just not sure why it can't read my changes.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide more details about what did you try? What version of Drupal core are you using? 7.x?

Comment: Could you please describe where is your theme folder located?

Comment: The version of drupal is 7.34 and the theme is located in sites/all/themes/
I am using openshift so the folder is a bit on a different location. However, the fact that when page.tbp,php is removed and caches are clear there is a fall back behavior it tell me that drupal sees the file is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Just see $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'] array in your template.php using template_preprocess_page. (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7).
It will guide you what happing there in you template system of enabled theme.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some module is messing up something. Try disabling the one by one to see will that help.